# Dynamic formula field

Tags: sobject, dynamic

How can i use dynamic field value in the formula field.
Like :- TEXT(contact__r.Contact_Title__c)

I want to deploy this formula field in my org without creating Contact_Title__c field on contact object. It is showing me the error Contact_Title__c field is not present on contact. How can i use this field dynamically inside the formula.?

Answer (score 1):

Formula fields can only refer following types of fields

1. Custom and standard fields on the object
2. Related lookups utpo 4 levels
3. Global variables like User, UserRole, custom Settings etc.

To answer your question, dynamic formulas are not possible.

More Details on Global Variables
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&language=en

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** *the following applies only to the visualforce pages, not formulas, my fault ;(*

You can use a dynamic reference to the objects field like this:

```
TEXT(contact__r["Contact_Title__c"])
```

[Dynamic Bindings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf.htm)

Comment: This is not working. I tried to create following formula field for contact -> ''+Account["id"]. This is throwing error as "Found Account

Comment: I created formula field using your reference but it thew an error:-

Comment: [19:20:54] Abhinav Bhatia: Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Syntax error. Found 'Payee__r' (Related field: Formula)
[19:21:00] Abhinav Bhatia: TEXT(Payee__r["Contact_Title__c"])